# Solving basic linear congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Solve for $x $ :
>   $$327x+208\equiv0 \mod 601$$

**What I tried:**
I tried to find the modular inverse of $x$ first, so that I would be able to multiply the equation with it, but no luck so far.

Comment: The euclidean algorithm lets you solve for the modular inverse of $327$.  Start there.

Comment: Why did you have no luck?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: There are many questions listed under *Related* that probably concern problems just like this one. Why not have a look to see if there's anything there to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Euclidean algorithm to determine the multiplicative inverse of $327$.
We see
$$
  601 = 1\cdot 601 + 0 \cdot 327 \\
  327 = 0\cdot 601 + 1 \cdot 327 \\
  274 = 1\cdot 601 + -1 \cdot 327 \\
  53 = -1\cdot 601 + 2 \cdot 327 \\
  9 = 6\cdot 601 + -11 \cdot 327 \\
  -1 = -37 \cdot 601 + 68 \cdot 327 \\
  1 = 37 \cdot 601 + -68 \cdot 327.
$$
Thus $327^{-1}\equiv -68 \equiv 533 \mod 601$.
Now it is simple, rewrite the equation
$$
  327 x \equiv - 208 \mod 601.
$$
Multiply by the inverse of $327$ this results in
$$
  x \equiv -208\cdot 533 \equiv 321 \mod 601.
$$

Comment: @OP That *forward* version of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm is explained at length [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242). There are over $150$ linked worked examples in its "Linked" questions list.

Comment: you forgot an inverse symbol ... @Math $327\equiv -274\bmod 601$

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I tried the same thing and got stuck at 9 due to some  flaws in my understanding of this algorithm but now I get it. Thanks again